# How to use viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am currently teaching myself swift and I am reading The Big Nerd Ranch 6th edition. In chapter 5 it says for a challenge try and update the background color based on the time of day. It says I need to override viewWillAppear. However I am unable to find any documentation that shows how to play with this. I can only find documentation explaining the differences between this and viewDidLoad. Any links that can help me understand the concept here and maybe show me an example would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/01/ios-essentials-the-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/ and any other article about `UIViewController` lifecycle

Comment: No, I never google anything before asking on stack overflow. I just expect results.

Comment: There's an example of overriding `viewWillAppear` in Chapter 14.

Answer (score 3):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)    
    //Your Code Here...  
}
```

Comment: You forgot the call to super.viewWillAppear